# Apache website relative path pointing to wrong url

Tags: php

So I'm trying to set up a local version of a website hosted on the cloud.

My relative path like this :

ex: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/style.css" />`

Translate to `http://localhost/css/style.css`

The issue : My site is in a folder like this : `http://localhost/mysite/`

So the URL should be `http://localhost/mysite/css/style.css`.

If I remove the first `/`, it will work. But as it's a dev copy of a prod website, I don't want to change this each time I deploy my modifications.

Do you guys know why it does that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the `/` it is calling from the root directory which is your case is set by your `httpd.conf`or `httpd.conf-vhosts`. If you want to use your current setup you can define a constant in a config file that's added to every page eg:

```
define( 'WS_URL' , 'http://localhost/mysite/' );
```

and then call it on your resources:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo WS_URL; ?>css/style.css" />
```

Better yet you should create a virtual host for each production where you can set the root directory if you are using (wamp or similar). It also makes it easier to maintain and use when you have specific urls set for each production eg: `http://mysite.local` etc.